# Put a condition formatting on a list box in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Can I use condition formatting on a list box in one of my forms?

This what the result of my form looks like.
[image]

In the design view the table I want to put condition formatting on, is in the far left. It's a list box with SQL query that select information from two tables.

```
SELECT 
T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_id, 
T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_salarie_nni, 
T_SALARIE.SALARIE_nom, 
T_SALARIE.SALARIE_prenom, 
T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_date_fin_emploi_actuel 
FROM 
T_EMPLOI INNER JOIN (T_SALARIE INNER JOIN T_SALARIE_EMPLOI ON T_SALARIE.SALARIE_NNI = T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_salarie_nni) ON T_EMPLOI.EMPLOI_identifiant = T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_emploi_identifiant WHERE (((T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_statut_id)=2) And ((T_SALARIE_EMPLOI.SALARIE_EMPLOI_emploi_identifiant)=Forms!F_Vue_Emploi.Form!EMPLOI_identifiant));
```

[image]

Unlike a text box, the formatting condition button doesn't show for my list box.

Condition formatting example:
if The first column (ID = 0) then put the whole row in a chosen color (red for example)

Comment: Use subform control instead of listbox.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this isn't possible with a listbox. As alternative you could make a subform as continuous or datasheet form. Then you can use conditional formatting .

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions. and I think the subform is solution.
Thank you once more !